# SQL exists not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the SQl query below which list the stores

Whenever i get "All city types" in the citytypename fields , i DO NOT need to list the other rows for the
particular storelocationid

Result

```
71    8    0    All City Types    West    Dhanalakshmi store     All Cities    All States
71    8    1    Tier 2            West    Dhanalakshmi store     Bangalore     Karnataka
71    8    2    Tier 2            West    Dhanalakshmi store     Ahmedabad     Gujarat
```

how i will rewrite my query for this?

```
SELECT  LL.StoreLocationID
       ,LC.[StoreID]
       ,ISNULL(LC.CityID,0) CityID
       ,ISNULL(C.CityTypeName,'All City Types') CityTypeName
       ,ISNULL(LL.RegionName,'All Regions') RegionName
       ,L.[Name] StoreName
       ,ISNULL(C.Name,'All Cities') AS CityName
       ,ISNULL(S.Name, 'All States') AS StateName
FROM [StoreCity] LC
    INNER JOIN [Store] L ON L.[StoreID] = LC.[StoreID] 
    INNER JOIN [StoreLocation] LL ON LL.StoreID=LC.StoreID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [City] C ON LC.CityID = C.CityID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [State] S ON C.StateID = S.StateID
WHERE StoreLocationID =  71
AND (
   /* current row is 'All City Types' */
   C.CityTypeName IS NULL
   OR 
   /* current row is not 'All City Types', 
      but there does not exist another row that is. */
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [StoreLocation] LL2 ON LL2
      INNER JOIN [StoreCity] LC2 ON LC2.[StoreID] = LL2.[StoreID]
      INNER JOIN [City] C2 ON C2.[CityID] = LC2.[CityID]
      WHERE LL2.StoreLocationID = LL.StoreLocationID
      AND C2.CityTypeName IS NULL
   )
)
```

Comment: from your question, I cannot determine what the tables contain, or what the cardinal relationships are between them (except City and state of course)  Are there many stores in each store lolcation? or is one store in multiple locations? or both? What is the relationship structure ????

Comment: Are these `NULL`s stored in `CityTypeName` or are they produced from the left outer joins?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the subquery in the WHERE clause? What criteria is it filtering out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to look for DISTINCT and possible a corresponding GROUP BY.

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(C.CityTypeName,'All City Types') CityTypeName FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  final .StoreLocationID
       ,final .[StoreID]
       ,final .CityID
       ,final .CityTypeName
       ,final .RegionName
       ,final .StoreName
       ,final .CityName
       ,final .StateName from ( SELECT  LL.StoreLocationID
       ,LC.[StoreID]
       ,ISNULL(LC.CityID,0) CityID
       ,ISNULL(C.CityTypeName,'All City Types') CityTypeName
       ,ISNULL(LL.RegionName,'All Regions') RegionName
       ,L.[Name] StoreName
       ,ISNULL(C.Name,'All Cities') AS CityName
       ,ISNULL(S.Name, 'All States') AS StateName FROM [StoreCity] LC
    INNER JOIN [Store] L ON L.[StoreID] = LC.[StoreID] 
    INNER JOIN [StoreLocation] LL ON LL.StoreID=LC.StoreID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [City] C ON LC.CityID = C.CityID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [State] S ON C.StateID = S.StateID WHERE StoreLocationID =  71 AND (    /* current row is 'All City Types' */   C.CityTypeName IS NULL    OR     /* current row is not 'All City Types', 
      but there does not exist another row that is. */    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [StoreLocation] LL2 ON LL2
      INNER JOIN [StoreCity] LC2 ON LC2.[StoreID] = LL2.[StoreID]
      INNER JOIN [City] C2 ON C2.[CityID] = LC2.[CityID]
      WHERE LL2.StoreLocationID = LL.StoreLocationID
      AND C2.CityTypeName IS NULL    ) ) ORDER BY FIELD("All City Types", CityTypeName) DESC ) as final group by final.StoreLocationID
```

Try this, not tested...